# Нужно ли обособлять "в конечном счете" в данных предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Нужно ли обособлять "в конечном счете" в данных предложениях?
Привожу в контексте. Это цитаты, переделать не могу.
Если где-то запятые не требуются, то хотелось бы знать, почему.

1) *Евросоюз те или иные деньги дает довольно большому количеству стран, рассматривая это как помощь развитию. Направлено это(,) **в конечном счете**(,) на то, чтобы в финансируемых странах не шли процессы дестабилизации.*

2) *Чем более гармонизированы будут нормы стран-партнеров с нормами ЕС, тем проще будет компаниям из ЕС работать в этих странах. Не будет барьеров в плане экономической деятельности. Возможно, и в плане передвижения людей. Это все(,) **в конечном счете**(,) благоприятно.*

3) *Если население страны поддерживает те нормы, которые в ЕС сформулированы в разных областях, и эти нормы являются правильным путем для государства, обеспечивая его внутреннюю стабильность и положительную динамику экономического развития, то это позитивный процесс. Вне зависимости от того, произойдет ли(,) **в конечном счете**(,) вступление в ЕС.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**в конечном счёте**
*наречное выражение*
Не требует постановки знаков препинания.
Неизм. В итоге, в результате всего. = В конце концов (в 1 знач.). Чаще с глаголами совершенного вида: как? в конечном счете согласиться, договориться…

*…В конечном счете каждая книга становится «говорящим лицом», то есть обращена к читателю…* (Ю. Тынянов)
*Есть одна битва, которую люди ведут непрерывно… это битва за хлеб, ибо она означает в конечном счете битву за жизнь на земле* (М. Алексеев).

[**Словарь-справочник по пунктуации**](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/85/%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%B5)
[**Учебный фразеологический словарь**](https://phraseologiya.academic.ru/92/%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%B5)

У некоторых классиков, правда, другое вИдение:

*Из непостижимого хаоса, вечно возникающих туманностей слагается, в конечном счёте, высшая форма природы — человеческий мозг* (Л. Н. Толстой. Большой учёный).
*Если мы знаем, что история человеческого общества – это история войн, то, в конечном счете, история народов – это борьба за правду* (Ч. Айтматов).

Во всех предложениях — по правилам — обособление не требуется: по смыслу "в конечном счете" легко заменяется на "в итоге".
Получается, что выделение наречного выражения запятыми — это авторское решение.

Answer (score 4):

"Словарь вводных слов сочетаний и предложений", O.A. Остроумова, О.Д. Фрамполь, говорит следующее:

Один из пунктов в общем обзоре:

> 5. Слова и сочетания слов, редко употребляющиеся в функции вводного
>      слова, поскольку эта функция для них нетипична. Фактически это случаи
>      индивидуального  авторского употребления слова в функции вводного.
>      Например: в принципе, в сущности, странно, в первую очередь, в конце
>      концов, **в конечном счете**...

В статье "В конечном итоге, в конечном счёте":

> 1. Редко употребляется в функции вводного для  выражения субъективного отношения к какому-либо факту  (= если подумать), интонационно
>      выделяется: *В конечном  счете, ну его в болото!* (М.Булгаков);

В каждом из приведенных в вопросе предложений *в конечном счёте* не является вводным и не требует выделения.

Answer (score 1):

Справочная служба сайта  Грамота.ру говорит, что запятые не нужны.

> [Вопрос № 239109](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=239109)
>    Здравствуйте! Правильно ли фразу В КОНЕЧНОМ СЧЕТЕ выделять с двух сторон запятыми? Спасибо!
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Наречное выражение *в конечном счете* не требует выделения знаками препинания.